# Graphing polynom in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, plot

```
function x = plotpint (coef, x1, x2,numpoints) 

%coef: polynom's coefficient array x1,x2 : intervals
%numpoints: the number of data points to be plotted

a=linspace(x1,x2,numpoints); % linspace of intervals and numpoints
b=polyval(coef,a); %values of given coef polynom for intervals
c=polyint(coef); % coef array of given coef's integral of polynom ( don't care here)
d=polyval(c,a); % values of c's polynom(integral of polynom) ( don't care here)
plot(a,b); % plotting polynom and integral of polynom
title('rer'); 

end
```

My plotpint function is here. For example I want to p(x) = x^2-4 which has roots -2 and +2. But when I tried to plot this polynom my graph shows that root is 0 like in image.

[image]

What should I do now? Where Am I wrong? How to fix this problem?

Comment: Try `coef = [1 0 -4]`

Comment: Thanks Ben Voigt, I fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem, you've graphed `y = x*x + 0*x + 4` correctly (according to your value of `coef`).

I do note that `.0004 * 10^4` and `.0000 * 10^4` are very hard to tell apart at that zoom level.  You may see what's going on much more easily using the range `-5:5` instead of `-150:150`.

FWIW, when interpreting any graph in MATLAB, start by looking at the axis scale.

[image]